# SP2013 - Problem with WorkFlows and InfoPath forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow

There is a SharePoint Server 2013 of a client of our that just cannot create infoPath forms for the Collect Data workflow action anymore. The error message is extremely vague and I could not find anything useful in the SP logs. We are just noticed that the Designer was not able to create de infoPath form for that action.

I'm thinking if there is a way to tell SharePoint to ASPX form instead a XSN one that, I believe, is the cause of this trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a reusable workflow wich SPD was able to create the XSN form.